# npm request module doesn't follow 301 redirects correctly

Tags: node.js, request, http-status-code-301

I have two urls:
`http://tbphoto3.bababian.com/upload7/fuguirenshen/201606/001169212894_m.jpg` which is 301 redirected
and `http://t.shuaishou.com/Get/168062675` which is 302 redirected.

But when I request to get the two with 
`js
request.defaults({
  proxy: 'my-proxy-address'
})`

only 302 redirect is returned successfully with final content.
The 301 redirect url returns body with lenth=0.

If I remove the `proxy` option, both urls will be followed and retrieved correctly.

Could anyone help me fix this please?

Comment: What proxy are you using?

Comment: @Yashua I have deployed a simple node proxy on another machine, the codes are just like the realization within this blog: http://www.catonmat.net/http-proxy-in-nodejs/

Comment: I could be mistaken but I think that the 301 may need to be handled by the proxy. While looking around I see that some proxies claim they do not support 301 hence my comment. It may be worth investigating along that route. For example: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/37